# Package iOS applications

Tags: ios, packaging

I am little confused about the packaging process for iOS application. One of my client already have a private distribution channel and want us to supply just the packaged file. Now what all do we need from client.... just Application Name, Application ID and certificates in P12 format?

Also how can we test the application on a real device, do we need to have developer license, if yes then can I reuse developer license to develop another application...

Sorry if it is a lame question... I am pretty new to iOS application packaging.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the application on a device is easy if you have XCode version 7 or more.
Simply plug the device via usb and run the app using the play button in XCode

You don't need to have a developer license or a paid developer account for testing. This can be done via your Apple ID also